# Why I cannot download Ubuntu desktop on Ubuntu 17 server (apt-get failed)

Tags: apt, server, 17.10, tasksel

First I install tasksel:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Then I updatedb

```
sudo updatedb
```

After that I update apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and Finally I run tasksel and choose **Ubuntu Desktop**

```
sudo tasksel
```

But I still get this error, why?

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
tasksel: apt-get failed (100)
```

Comment: Why do you say "still"?

Comment: I mean even after updating apt-get, I am still getting the same error